# Copying just the matches to a register?

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression, register

I'm trying to copy just the matches in my regex search to a register in VIM on windows.

That said, I [found](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy_search_matches#Copy_matches) the following script for doing this:

```
function! CopyMatches(reg)
  let hits = []
  %s//\=len(add(hits, submatch(0))) ? submatch(0) : ''/ge
  let reg = empty(a:reg) ? '+' : a:reg
  execute 'let @'.reg.' = join(hits, "\n") . "\n"'
endfunction
command! -register CopyMatches call CopyMatches(<q-reg>)
```

However, when I run the script and try to paste my matches from register a, it comes back blank.  Is there something else that I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Works for me. Did you run a search before running `:CopyMatches a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note this line:

```
%s//\=len(add(hits, submatch(0))) ? submatch(0) : ''/ge
```

The search pattern is empty, which means it will re-use that last pattern that was used. So, this command relies on you having run `/foo` before running this command.